# Office.context.document.url does not give updated name/url

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-addins, office-js

Repro steps - 
1- Create a basic task pane apps for Office for word

2  -  use following HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function GetFileURL() {
        console.log("Url = "+Office.context.document.url);
        document.getElementById("urlLabel").innerHTML = Office.context.document.url;
      }

      function Reset() {
        document.getElementById("urlLabel").innerHTML = "";
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body class="ms-font-l ms-landing-page">
    <input id="btn1" type="button" onclick="GetFileURL()" value="Get File URL "></input><br>
    <input id="btn2" type="button" onclick="Reset()" value="Reset"></input><br>
    <p id="urlLabel">File Url Displayed here</p>
    <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

3- Use the following code on a button click to get a URL name visible at the top

```
function GetFileURL() {
        console.log("Url = " + Office.context.document.url);
        document.getElementById("urlLabel").innerHTML = Office.context.document.url;
    }
```

4- Load the Office app in Word online document

5- Edit in Word Online

6- The document name is visible at the top in form of the title 
example -  Sample -Saved

7- If you click and get the URL (document name) as visible

Now if you change the name directly in the title bar, and then click on the add-in button, you still see the old URL
If you reload the document, then and load the add-in again, then you see the correct updated URL.

I am trying to understand if there is a way by which we can get hold of the new document name immediately without the need to reload the document.

Any pointers on this behavior will really help us move forward

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this - we need to use 
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync